# wrap text in single column using columnizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm using columnizer jQuery plugin to split my content into columns. Using the plugin I'm able to split into two columns, but I'm facing problems with the title showing in one column and content text showing in another column.

My question is: How can I force to show one article content and its title in a single column? Please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/narendar_medoju/u4syu6ew/6/).

```
[Wrap text in single column][1]
```

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/narendar_medoju/u4syu6ew/6/) **Title 6** should be shown in the second column or its description should show in the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class "dontsplit" to the article.

```
$('article').addClass('dontsplit');
```

Just before calling columnize.